# Google play login different GSM carriers

Tags: gsm

I moved to the USA from Kenya with my android handset, but am unable to log in to google play on my new network, T-mobile.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Contact Google...

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings > Applications > Manage Applications. Select Google Play Store from the list. Select Clear data. Then try using Google Play again.